# HTML parsing with HtmlAgilityPack in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, html-parsing, windows-store-apps, html-agility-pack, object-reference

i'm parsing HTML code to get Image Link in a "Windows Store Application"
i'm Using Html Agility Pack !
Here The Code :

```
    async void LoidContent()
        {
            foreach (var feedItem in feedData.Items)
            {
               HttpClient httpClient  = new HttpClient();
               var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(feedItem.Link);
               HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.Load(stream);

                // GET IMAGE
                var div = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(
                    d =>
                    d.Name == "div" && d.Attributes["class"] != null && d.Attributes["class"].Value == "pika-stage img");

                var img = div.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
                if (img != null)
                {
                    string imgLinks = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
                    feedItem.Image = new Uri(imgLinks);
                }
}}
```

sometimes the application crashes
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in this line

```
var img = div.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Do you sometimes have a documents that has no `div` elements? Or none that have a `pika-stage img` class?

Comment: No ! all documents respect the same template ( generated by a CMS ) .

Comment: It's probably the div has no img descendants. Do you have a sample HTML to test?

Answer (score 0):

Before this:

```
var img = div.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault();
```

Check for `null`:

```
if ((div != null) && (div.Descendants("img") != null))
{
    // the rest of your code
}
```